# How create multi-line curl string, with variables contained within single and double quotes?

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, curl, heredoc

I am trying to send a query to an ElasticSearch database using the curl command,
but am having difficulty building the string using bash scripting.

First of all, without any variables, the following command works successfully:

```
curl -XGET << "EOT" "stg-myserver.stg.xyz2.bdd.local:9200/stg_index-2020.03.10/_data?format=csv&fields_name=personId,totalPrice,regDatetime&_source=" -d '
{
  "query": { 
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
              "range" : {
                          "regDatetime" : {
                              "gte" : "2020-03-11T08:00:00+09:00",
                              "lte" : "2020-03-11T08:59:59+09:00"
                          }
              }
            }]
        }
    }
}'
EOT
```

However, when trying to substitute a variable, for the regDatetime values, the query fails.

```
START_TIME='2020-03-11T08:00:00+09:00'
END_TIME='2020-03-11T08:59:59+09:00'

curl -XGET << "EOT" "stg-myserver.stg.xyz2.bdd.local:9200/stg_index-2020.03.10/_data?format=csv&fields_name=personId,totalPrice,regDatetime&_source=" -d '
{
  "query": { 
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
              "range" : {
                          "regDatetime" : {
                              "gte" : "$START_TIME",
                              "lte" : "$END_TIME"
                          }
              }
            }]
        }
    }
}'
EOT
```

After executing the second statement, I receive the following error:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse date field [$START_TIME]...

How can I access START_TIME and END_TIME?
Is using heredoc a reasonable solution, or can anyone recommend a less error-prone approach?

Comment: Why are you using a here-document (the `<<"EOT"` bit) here at all? That long bunch of JSON is in a single-quoted argument, so the here-doc winds up empty, and I don't think `curl` is even going to try to read from it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the double quote from the `EOT` keyword.

```
curl -XGET 'stg-myserver.stg.xyz2.bdd.local:9200/stg_index-2020.03.10/_data?format=csv&fields_name=personId,totalPrice,regDatetime&_source=' -d @- << EOT
{ 
   ...
}
EOT
```

As said in `man bash`:

> If word is **unquoted**, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion (...)

That said, I advise to use a tool that is JSON aware to forge your date, like `jq`:

```
jq -c -n --arg s "$START_TIME" --arg e "$END_TIME" '{ query: { bool: { filter: [ { range: { regDateTime : { gte: $s, lte: $e } } } ] }}}'
```

This only insert the start time `s` and the end time `e` inside the JSON data. The advantage is that you're sure that the data is correct JSON.

This can be integrated with your command like this:

```
START_TIME='2020-03-11T08:00:00+09:00'
END_TIME='2020-03-11T08:59:59+09:00'
json_data=$(jq -c -n --arg s "$START_TIME" --arg e "$END_TIME" '{ query: { bool: { filter: [ { range: { regDateTime : { gte: $s, lte: $e } } } ] }}}')
url='stg-myserver.stg.xyz2.bdd.local:9200/stg_index-2020.03.10/_data?format=csv&fields_name=personId,totalPrice,regDatetime&_source='
curl -XGET "$url" -d "$json_data"
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes, ideally, I would be able to use jq - but unfortunately, I don't have permission to install this on the machine within the time needed. 

Also, I tried removing the double quotes from EOT, but I still get the same "failed to parse date field [$START_TIME]" error.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but you must remove the single quote around your data, after the `-d`